# passing text area value via ajax with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i am trying to pass two values to php file via ajax

my code is like this

**PHP** :

```
<?php 
$name="Name with spaces";
?>
```

**JS** :

```
var yourMessage = $("input#message").val();   
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "send_message.php",
    data: "yourName="+ <?=$name?> +"&yourMessage="+ yourMessage,
    success: function(html){........
```

its working fine but

i am getting two problems.

1. name is in php variable and it had spaces, it gives error of spaces but i need to have same name with spaces on **send_message.php**
2. yourMessage is getting value from `<textarea>` and if there is any return keys i need also to pass on **send_message.php**.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replacing

```
data: "yourName="+ <?=$name?> +"&yourMessage="+ yourMessage,
```

with

```
data: {"yourName":"<?=$name?>","yourMessage":yourMessage},
```

might solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

The best way i think is serialize the data. It reduces many problem.
Try this

```
<?php 
$name=serialize('Name with spaces');
?> 

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "send_message.php",
data: 'yourName='+ <?php echo $name?> +'&yourMessage='+ yourMessage,
```

echo the name.
I think this will help you.